# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Set' conflict with asp/sql code

Tags: sql-server

When I write a simple "success" or "failure" to the sql table field I do not receive this error, but when I include a verbose command output that is ~3500 characters, I get the error in the title. The sql database field is a type of text field, which is supposed to have a 2.1 billion character limit?

What am I doing wrong?

```
DBConnectionlib.DBClass dbWrite = new DBConnectionlib.DBClass();
dbWrite.connectionInformation = @"Server=tcp:xxxxx,1111 ;Database=xxxxx;Trusted_Connection=false;UID=xxxxx;Pwd=xxxxx;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;Timeout=60;MultiSubnetFailover=True";               
dbWrite.tableName = "xxxxx";
string tableNameWrite = "xxxxx";

List<string> dataItems = new List<string>();

dbWrite.insertStatement = "insert into " + tableNameWrite + " (dateTime, changeMakersSamAccount, changeMakersDisplayName, " +
                "changeMakersIp,changeMakersComputerName,accountBeingChangedSamAccount,accountBeingChangedDisplayName,domainControllerUsed," +
                "changeDescription,fileNameUploaded,result)" +
                "VALUES" +
                "('" + logging_dateTime + "', '" + logging_changeMakersSamAccount + "', '" + logging_changeMakersDisplayName + "', '" 
                + logging_changeMakersIp + "', '" + logging_changeMakersComputerName + "', '" + logging_accountBeingChangedSamAccount + "', '" 
                + logging_accountBeingChangedDisplayName + "', '" + logging_domainControllerUsed + "', '" + logging_changeDescription + "', '" 
                + logging_fileNameUploaded + "', '" + logging_result + "')";

string dbResults = dbWrite.writeToSqlDatabase();
```

Comment: Perhaps the `result` data has embedded quotes. Use a parameterize query to solve this and other issues with your code.

Comment: **[Little Bobby Tables they called him.](https://xkcd.com/327/)** He later changed his name to "Robert O'Set" ;)

Comment: Hello. I tested what you said and replaced all quotes with an ** and all single quotes with an * and it recorded successfully. What can I do short of a string replace to fix this?

The verbose output has both " and ' in it. The " are escaped with a back slash, the ' are not escaped at all.

Comment: Parameterized queries avoid the need to escape quotes entirely, In addition to this and security benefits, they avoid the need to format date stings, specify decimal separators, and improve performance with cache reuse. Use parameters and your problem is solved.